# Shrink Sidemenu package - Navigate to new screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

I'm using the ([Shrink Sidemenu](https://pub.dev/packages/shrink_sidemenu)) from pub.dev

The package is great but I don't understand how exactly we can navigate to a new screen.

The docs never say how to.

The below code is taken from the `EXAMPLE` in the package website

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SideMenu(
      ...
      child: IgnorePointer(
         ...
         child: Scaffold(
         ...
         body: // Display the selected screen here,
         ),
      ),
   );
}


Widget buildMenu() {
   return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
         child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
               ListTile(
               onTap: () { // What code should I input here},
               leading: const Icon(Icons.home, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
               title: const Text("Home"),
               textColor: Colors.white,
               dense: true,
            ),
            ListTile(
               onTap: () { // What code should I input here},
               leading: const Icon(Icons.verified_user, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
               title: const Text("Profile"),
               textColor: Colors.white,
               dense: true,
            ),
            ListTile(
               onTap: () { // What code should I input here},
               leading: const Icon(Icons.settings, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
               title: const Text("Settings"),
               textColor: Colors.white,
               dense: true,
            ),
         ],
      ),
   );
}
```

Can someone please help me understand how to navigate to a new screen with this package?
I have been stuck on this for a long time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Navigator` for that.

```
Widget buildMenu() {
   return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 50.0),
         child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
               ListTile(
               onTap: () { 

final _state = _sideMenuKey.currentState;
                
                  _state.closeSideMenu(); // close side menu
            
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>NewPage());

},
               leading: const Icon(Icons.home, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
               title: const Text("Home"),
               textColor: Colors.white,
               dense: true,
            ),
            ListTile(
               onTap: () { // What code should I input here},
               leading: const Icon(Icons.verified_user, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
               title: const Text("Profile"),
               textColor: Colors.white,
               dense: true,
            ),
            ListTile(
               onTap: () { // What code should I input here},
               leading: const Icon(Icons.settings, size: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
               title: const Text("Settings"),
               textColor: Colors.white,
               dense: true,
            ),
         ],
      ),
   );
}
```

Comment: I want to make full use of the menu that I'm using
When I click on a menu item - then I want to close the menu and display the new screen

Comment: I've updated my code